# What is this word for untaxed tithe in Virginia in 1761?

Tags: palaeography, 18th-century, virginia, taxation-records

I need help reading this word (?Tist?) that keeps occuring in the [Chesterfield tithe list for 1761 in Colony of Virginia](http://www.binnsgenealogy.com/MembersOnlyArea/pdfs/Chesterfield/1761Tith/09.pdf):

[image]

It seems to be repeated on each entry that is not counted for the tithes.

What is the word/abbreviation at end of line of such entries?  Something like `Tist`

Another example:

[image]

And another:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is '*List*'.

As far as I can make out,the name preceding the word *List* is that of the 'Master' and the names that follow are those of their household, slaves or servants.

So, for the extracts in your question, we have:

First image:

> Mary Clay's List
>
> ...

Second image:

> John Sturdivant's List
>
> ...

Third image:

> Obadiah Smith's List
>
> ...

---

The Library of Virginia has published a series of Research Notes, which I've found very helpful over the years. Research Notes Number 17 describes [Colonial Tithables](http://www.lva.virginia.gov/public/guides/rn17_tithables.htm).  Every head of household or master was required to submit a list of those liable for tithes. Note that after 1723,

> In addition to their ***tithable lists***, all masters were required to list the names of every person between the ages of ten and sixteen “for whom any benefit of tending Tobacco is allowed by this Act.” In tithable lists, masters were required to distinguish which persons were primarily employed in the cultivation of tobacco.

- (my emphasis)

There are also linked pages on the associated legislative history, and a case study that you might find useful.

Comment: Yes, slaves are listed last without last names.  The `List` only occurs on tithe entries where the first entry is not counted (i.e., not taxed) so it could be for being deceased or female or under age male.  List doesn't make sense to me as a result.

Comment: @WilliamKF Sorry. That should have been "_household, slaves or servants_".  Limitations of a small screen.